# CSS background gradient faded wave colors

Tags: html, css, gradient, radial-gradients

This could be extremely easy, but I'm not very familiar with CSS effects, but is it possible to create a background that mimics the gradient of the underlying image?
The background is repeated vertically.
[image]

---
The closest I have been able to get is as follows:

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top right, #0D0934, transparent),
              radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, #3A0927, transparent),
              radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom left, #0D0934, transparent),
              radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom right, #3A0927, transparent);
}
```

P.S. The visualization seems buggy in this code snippet

Comment: min-height:100% to html element

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked for, I asked how to reproduce the gradient of the image above. I don't know why the question was closed.

Answer (score -2):

`body{ background: radial-gradient(red, blue); }`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.